# Bilinear forms and congruent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $\phi, \psi: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be two bilinear forms.

I'm investigating the relation between the follwing two propositions:

> 1. There exist an invertible linear operator $L$ on $V$ such that  $\psi(Lv,Lw)=\phi(v,w)$ $\forall v,w \in V$
> 2. $\forall$ $ \mathcal{V}$ basis of $V$ the two representing matrices $A_{\phi}^{\mathcal{V}}$, $A_{\psi}^{\mathcal{V}}$ are congruent

This is my work:

$(1) \implies (2): $ choose a basis $\mathcal{V}$ of $V$. Suppose $P_L^{\mathcal{V}}$ represents $L$ with respect to $\mathcal{V}$. Let $[v]_{\mathcal{V}}$ denote the vector of coordinates of $v \in V$ in $\mathcal{V}$. Then $\psi(Lv,Lw)=[Lv]_{\mathcal{V}}^T A_{\psi}^{\mathcal{V}} [Lw]_\mathcal{V}=[v]_{\mathcal{V}}^T P_{\mathcal{V}}^T A_{\psi}^{\mathcal{V}} P_{\mathcal{V}}[w]_{\mathcal{V}}= [v]_{\mathcal{V}}^T A_{\phi}^{\mathcal{V}} [w]_{\mathcal{V}}=\phi(v,w)$ for every $v,w \in V$.

$(2) \implies (1)$: I know that $\forall$ $\mathcal{V}$ basis of $V$ there's an invertible matrix $P_{\mathcal{V}}$ that may depend on $\mathcal{V}$ such that $P_{\mathcal{V}}^T A_{\psi}^{\mathcal{V}} P_{\mathcal{V}}= A_{\phi}^{\mathcal{V}}$. Calling $L_{\mathcal{V}}$ the linear operator associated to $P_{\mathcal{V}}$ one can conclude the following:

> $\forall$ $\mathcal{V}$ basis of $V$ there's an invertible linear operator $L_{\mathcal{V}}$ such that $\psi(L_{\mathcal{V}}v,L_{\mathcal{V}}w)=\phi(v,w)$ $\forall v,w \in V$

Do you think I can get rid of the dependence of $\mathcal{V}$ in $L$ to obtain the second proposition? Any hint or counterexample is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you prove $\psi(Lv,Lw) = \phi(v,w)$ in $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, when you already have assumed it?

Comment: You define $L$ via $[Lx]_{\mathcal V} := P_{\mathcal V}[x]_{\mathcal V}$. I would write the whole thing in terms of an isomorphism anyways.

Comment: @amsmath I'm proving the congruence of the matrices using the hypothesis: it is implied by the chain of equations

Comment: But you write it in a non-conformal (if not false) way. The third equality sign is actually the one you want to prove. So, you can actually not write it in the middle of your computations. You should start with the expression to its left and then use the equality that you have for the bilinear forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approach $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ we can prove that $(2) \Rightarrow (3):= \exists B,B'$ basis of $V$ : $M_{B}(\phi) = M_{B'}(\psi)$ and then that $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$. This should solve the problem of $\mathcal{V}$

$(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ Let's fix $B$ basis of $V$. We know that $M_{B}(\phi) = P^{\top}M_{B}(\psi)P, \hspace{0.2cm} P \in GL(V)$, where $GL(V)$ denotes the group of the invertible endomorphisms of V.

Besides, from change of basis theory we know that $\exists! B'$ such that $M_{B', B}(id) = P$

In the basis $B'$ we have :

$$x^{\top}M_{B'}(\psi)y = (Px)^{\top}M_{B}(\psi)(Py) \hspace{0.2cm} \forall x,y \in \mathbb{K}^{n}$$

Where $x,y$ are thought as vectors in the basis $B'$.

Hence $$M_{B'}(\psi) = P^{\top}M_{B}(\psi)P \Rightarrow M_{B}(\phi) = M_{B'}(\psi) \hspace{0.2cm}\Box.$$

Now we prove that $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$ :

Similarly, let $P=M_{B',B}(id)$. Obviously $P \in GL(V)$.

It is true that $P$ is really what we're looking for, or in other words isometry between $(V,\phi), (V,\psi)$

(If thought as matrix of the endormorphism $f$ that maps $B\to B'$),

In fact, calling $[]_{B}$ the isomorpshism of coordinates $\forall v,w \in V, [v]_{B}=x,[w]_{B}=y$ we have :

$$\phi(v,w) = x^{\top}M_{B}(\phi)y = x^{\top}M_{B'}(\psi)y = x^{\top}P^{\top}M_{B}(\psi)Py = \psi(f(v),f(w)) \hspace{0.2cm} \Box.$$

(If $P$ is thought as matrix of $f$).

I think this answers your question, let me know if there is anything that doesn't feel right to you.

Comment: Thanks! However I don't understand what $M_{B', B}(id) = P$ means (hence what result you're talking about). Do you mean that for any basis $B$ and invertible matrix $P$ there's only one basis $B'$ s.t. $P$ is the matrix of the change of basis $B \rightarrow B'$ ?

Comment: Yes i was underlining the fact change of basis could always be seen as an invertible matrix $P$.